# DynamoDB items are not getting inserted at first request from lambda need to make 4-5 requests

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have one DynamoDB table with one **Local Secondary Index (LSI)**. When i try to insert new item from local machine then it gets inserted in first request but when i deploy the same code to AWS lambda then it takes 4-5 requests and then inserts the new records. I have kept **auto scaling** for the table is it affecting it..?

Code for inserting Record

```
async function addLogstoDynamoDB(body, tries = 1) {
  var params = {
    TableName: config.tableName,
    Item: {
      start: body.timestamp,      //Local secondary index
      number: "+" + body.cli,     //Primary key
      id: "CON-" + body.callid,   //Sort key
    },
  };

  let result = await DynamoDB.insertRecord(params);
  if (result.error !== null && tries < 3) {
    console.log(result.error);
    tries++;
    addLogstoDynamoDB(body, tries);
  }
}
```

DynamoDB.insertRecord() code

```
static insertRecord(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      dynamoDB.put(params, function (error, data) {
        resolve({ error, data });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: We can't help unless you provide code and symptoms of the failing requests.

Comment: @jarmod I have updated question with my code, please have a look

Comment: What errors are being logged that cause you to retry? Also, note that all DynamoDB SDK calls support promises natively: you can write `await dynamoDB.put(params).promise()`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lambda aborts the background process running after returning response from main exports function so this was causing the issue. My main lambda function was returning response before adding record to DynamoDB

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `await DynamoDB.insertRecord(params);` you should just call `await dynamoDB.put(params).promise()`. No need for you to wrap that into an extra function.